# Kdenlive does not seem to be leveraging proxy clips

Tags: linux, kdenlive, intermediate

I am trying to edit some 4K clips in Kdenlive and so I would like to use the [proxy clips](https://kdenlive.org/en/project/kdenlive-proxy-clips/) feature to speed up editing experience.

I have enabled the feature by default:

[image]

I've also checked that it is enabled for the project:

[image]

However, it does not look like any proxy clips are actually generated — neither when I add clips to the Project Bin, nor when I later drag them onto the timeline. Monitor navigation is still as slow as without the proxy feature enabled. Neither I can see any proxy clips on the disk in the project cache folder.

How to get the proxies to work?

- Kdenlive 20.12.3
- MLT 6.24.0
- OS: PureOS Byzantium